# Create a new dataframe with only duplicated rows

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I would like to have a new dataframe with only rows that are duplicated in the previous df. 
I tried to assign a new column that it is true if there are duplicates and then select only rows that are true. However I got 0 entities. I am sure that I have duplicates in the df
I want to keep in the old dataframe the first rows and remove all the other duplicates. 
Column with duplicate values is called 'merged'

```
df=df.assign(
    is_duplicate= lambda d: d.duplicated()
).sort_values('merged').reset_index(drop=True)
df2= df.loc[df['is_duplicate'] == 'True']
```

Comment: `duplicated` returns bools not str. Use `df.loc[df['is_duplicate']]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `loc` should be removed:

```
df[df.duplicated()]
```

Or your solution cannot be used with `.reset_index(drop=True)`, because then filtered another rows, also sorting should be better before or after solution:

```
df = df.assign(is_duplicate= lambda d: d.duplicated())
df2= df[df['is_duplicate']]
```

Comment: I think I also specify `keep = False` vs other

Answer (score 0):

They are not strings, they are booleans, so use:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['is_duplicate']]
```